# Center TextView without overlapping Image (centerHorizontal AND toRightOf)

Tags: android, android-layout

I already spent around 2-3 hours finding a solution. But no matter which stackoverflow answer I tried, it wasn't working properly.

All I need is a simple layout (within a CardView) with an ImageView at the left and a **text in the center of the layout (relative to its parent)** that won't overlap with the image.

The TextView is centered when I set `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` but if my text is too long it overlaps my image at the left. If I set `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/answer1_image"` my text won't overlap, but isn't centered. With both params together the TextView isn't centered too.

Here is a screenshot of my problem and my XML code of the first 2 cards:

[image: Layout preview]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".QuestionsActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/answer1_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:onClick="answer1_submitted"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/answer1_image"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/answer1_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/answer1_image"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="@string/answer1"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/answer2_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:onClick="answer2_submitted"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/answer2_image"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/answer2_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/answer2"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
...
```

Comment: `TextView` method `hasOverlappingRendering` may help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you search for: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html

To create distance between the `ImageView` and your `TextView` add `marginRight` in your specific `ImageView`.

Comment: Thanks, but this will add a fix margin to the left of my answer text. The behaviour I would like to have is the text always being centered. So if I have "a really long answer to my question text" the text will start right next to the image.

Comment: Do you search for: android:textAlignment="center"

Comment: So give the TextView the space right the imageView with the "marginRight" thing and add android:textAlignment="center" to the textView. So in case you have a longer answer the text will be closer to the imageView but not over it.

Comment: Setting a "layout_marginRight" to the ImageView has no effect since the TextView will start at the beginning. So I would still need "layout_toRightOf" in my textview, which won't help me as described above.

Comment: Sorry, I would be happy with it if the text is in the middle of the textView between the pic and the right side of my screen, I have no idea how to solve your problem in xml. In that case i would try to solve that problem in java with sth. like elementAt().

Comment: Yeah, maybe I have a too precise idea of how it should look like. I think I will go with the "maxWidth" or a fix left margin. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I could think of in your case is, remove `toRightOf` and give `left margin` to `textView` or `right margin` to `ImageView` as ImageView's size

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/answer1_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:onClick="answer1_submitted"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/answer1_image"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/answer1_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/answer1"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I already tried to use layout margins instead "toRightOf".
The problem is, when I set my TextView to "wrap_content" and "centerHorizontal" it will ignore its margin.
And if I set it to "match_parent" it will respect the margin but I can only center the text inside the TextView (by "gravity" oder "textAlignment"). But this way the text has the margin as offset to the parents center.

Answer (score 0):

One "solution" I came up with was to remove `toRightOf` and therefor set `maxWidth` in my TextView. This way the answer Text is at least always centered and cant overlay the image. But it also won't use the space at the right if the text is longer. Not really satisfactory. Still hoping someone has a better solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Check this:**

Just use following `TextView` Code into your Layout (No HardCoding):

```
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/answer1_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/answer1_image"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/answer1_image"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/answer1"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Working Fine !!

*Changes in TextView:*

- Change `TextView` `layout_width` into `match_parent` and `layout_height` into `wrap_content`
- Remove/Delete:   `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                  android:layout_centerInParent="true"`
- Add `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Just look at this simple step that would help you resolve this issue.

1. Add parent `Framelayout` that width should be match parent
2. Add your `ImageView` into your parent `Framelayout` than assign layout_gravity to left
3. Add your `TextView` widget into your same parent `Framelayout` than assign layout_gravity center_horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to use the relativelayout. If not you can add a Linearlayout and weightsum for achieving this.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightsum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/answer2_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer2_text"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/answer2"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```